# How can we display full post on home page rather than excerpt

Tags: custom-post-types, excerpt

I have a [puzzle](https://askpuzzle.com/) website where i am looking for the option to display full question on the home page rather than excerp. Just a note that questions are custom posts. Is there any way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the homepage can show whatever you want it to.

First, look through your theme's files to figure out what file specifically is being used for the homepage. Sometimes it is `home.php`; other times `front-page.php`. (If your theme shows a static Page, it can also be other templates - but it doesn't sound like that's the case here.) Sometimes the file that controls the homepage includes a different file using `get_template_part()`.

Once you determine which file is being used, you can create a Child Theme:

1. Create a new folder in `/wp-content/themes/`.
2. Create a new `style.css` file inside the folder and include at a minimum this comment:

   /*
   Theme Name: WPSE Child
   Template: nameofparenttheme
   */

You'll have to sub in "nameofparenttheme" with your actual theme. For example, if you are using the Twenty Fifteen theme as the parent, "twentyfifteen" is the template name. This tells WordPress "this is a child theme - if any files are missing here, look in the parent theme for them."

3. Copy the file in the parent theme that controls your homepage - copy it with the same name, into your child theme folder. Change just the part where it says

`the_excerpt()`

to

`the_content()`.

Keep in mind that if you are editing a template part, that will also affect other pages - wherever else that template part is called. So, if you only want to show the full post on the homepage and not elsewhere, you may instead want to copy `front-page.php` or `home.php` (the main file, not the `get_template_part()` and just replace the `get_template_part()` portion with your own code to format the post(s) however you want, including wrapper HTML and the full post content itself.

Comment: I pretty much agree with you, I have created child theme and also found the template that is being used but the code inside is not that simple I expected. Here is the code `if ($excerpt_questions != "on") {
           $question_excerpt = (isset($question_excerpt) && $question_excerpt != ""?$question_excerpt:40);?>
           <p><?php discy_excerpt($question_excerpt,$excerpt_type,$read_more_question);?></p>
          <?php }` just trying to understand how to change it.

Comment: It sounds like your theme is using custom excerpt functions - if you look in `functions.php` you should be able to see where things are defined and what each one is doing. It's hard to read in a comment where the formatting and indention aren't enabled. :)

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your functions.php file:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 30;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Change "30" to a big number so the excerpt length is increased.

Comment: I also though something like this will work, but unfortunately I can see full post but all content line by line. I want full post to show in proper order including line beak, page break etc.